# How do rolling updates on website work

Tags: web-services, web-applications, hateoas

Lets say I have a website with 4 webapp server and 1 HAProxy before them to do load balancing. Now I want to update my webapp with new api/v2 and I start the rolling update. My webapp is doing HATEOAS so lets assume that 1 instance got updated and it sent a link like api/v2/dothis to a clinet. 
Now the client made a request on this link and HAProxy directed it to 3rd server in the cluster which is still running the old webapp and doesn't know about api/v2. 
How do people solve this problem in general, how do websites do rolling updates without disrupting the service.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of these options

- **Option a:** Once you
  updated instance 1, shut down all the other instances so all the
  traffic goes to instance 1 (if this is even possible with the load
  you might expect. You could do this at a time when your one instance
  would be capable). Update instance 2 with the new webapp and bring it
  online, continue with all the other instances.
- **Option b:** Keep all the available resources in a place to where all
  your servers can check whether the resources exists on another webapp
  instance if they do not have it themselves (yet).

I feel that **option a** would be best, since you would not have to maintain another server/system for brokerage.

Comment: Option a is what I also thought, updating half of the running instances at one go and switching. But I wanted to validate what I am doing or if there is any better way. Thanks.